# Line clipping by LiangBarsky algorithm c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, graphics, clipping

I have a Liang Barsky algorithm implemented in c# but there's something wrong because it sometimes returns points outside the rectangle bounds like in this case:

p1=(516,546) and p2=(0,0) 
R=0;
L=511;
T=511;
B=0;

also how can i indicate that the line is totally outside the rectangle

```
    private void LiangBarsky( PointF P1,PointF P2,float R,float L,float T,float B)
    {
        try
        {

            float Tmin = 0;
            float Tmax = 1;
            float Tl, Tr, Tt, Tb;
            Tl = (L - P1.X) / (P2.X - P1.X);
            Tr = (R - P1.X) / (P2.X - P1.X);
            Tt = (T - P1.Y) / (P2.Y - P1.Y);
            Tb = (B - P1.Y) / (P2.Y - P1.Y);
            if (0 < Tl && Tl < 1.0)
            {
                if (InnerProduct(P1, P2, new Point(0, 1)) == EnteringPoint)
                    Tmin = Tl;
                else
                    Tmax = Tl;
                test = true;
            }
            if (0 < Tr && Tr < 1)
            {
                if (InnerProduct(P1, P2, new Point(0, -1)) == EnteringPoint)
                    Tmin = Tr;
                else
                    Tmax = Tr;
                test = true;
            }
            if (0 < Tt && Tt < 1)
            {
                if (InnerProduct(P1, P2, new Point(1, 0)) == EnteringPoint)
                    Tmin = Tt;
                else
                    Tmax = Tt;
                test = true;
            }
            if (0 < Tb && Tb < 1)
            {
                if (InnerProduct(P1, P2, new Point(-1, 0)) == EnteringPoint)
                    Tmin = Tb;
                else
                    Tmax = Tb;
                test = true;
            }
            if ((Tmin < Tmax) /*&& (Tmin!=0 )&&(Tmax!=1)*/)
            {

                P1 = new PointF((P1.X + (P2.X - P1.X) * Tmin), (P1.Y + (P2.Y - P1.Y) * Tmin));
                P2 = new PointF((P1.X + (P2.X - P1.X) * Tmax), (P1.Y + (P2.Y - P1.Y) * Tmax));
                Indtxt.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }
            else
            {

                if(P1.Y>T  && P1.X>L && P2.X>L && P2.Y>T)
                    Indtxt.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


    }
    private int InnerProduct(PointF LineP1, PointF LineP2, Point NormalVector)
    {
        PointF P1_P2 = new PointF(LineP2.X - LineP1.X, LineP2.Y - LineP1.Y);
        if (((P1_P2.X * NormalVector.X) + (P1_P2.Y * NormalVector.Y)) <= 0)
            return EnteringPoint;//0 as entering point ans 1 as exiting point
        else
            return ExitingPoint;
    }
```

- i translated the [algorith](http://www.netgraphics.sk/liang-barskys-line-clipping-algorithm) into the previous code so i might missed some concepts

Comment: Your problem description _"does not work well"_ is about equally informative as going to the doctor with a strained pinky toe and telling him/her that _"it hurts somewhere"_ :)

Comment: i meant that it returns points out of the rectangle bounds like in this case p1=(516,546) and p2=(0,0) R=0; L=511; T=511; B=0; ...i took the algorithm from this link http://www.netgraphics.sk/liang-barskys-line-clipping-algorithm and translated it into a code :) so may be i missed some concepts or something..

Comment: okay, could you edit your original question and add that extra information in it? Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, does the L-B algorithm you copied assume that R > L? That would be a natural assumption, but in the sample input you gave, which doesn't work right, R < L. For example if you let L=0 and R=511, does that fix the problem?

Comment: THanks @LarsH i fixed that :) but it does not work as the applet provided in the website i pointed to. but this fixed some the porblems,Thanks

Comment: It might help if you state exactly what answer is returned in the problem case that you mentioned. I'm having trouble seeing how your `LiangBarsky()` method returns any data at all, since you are replacing the contents of P1 and P2. Also, you may need to tweak the code `... == EnteringPoint` to be less sensitive to floating-point inaccuracy. Do you want `0.9999 == 1` to return True? Caveat: I'm not a C# expert.